# Swapping classes when input is not valid, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Im only starting to learn jquery, trying to validate my html forms.
I want  inputs to be red when there is no string so I set all inputs under class= "valid" to start and when empty field being submitted I want jquery to swap valid class to not_valid.
I manage to do that part but I need those classes back to normal when form is re-submitted. 
Can anyone please help me? thx

```
 $('.submit_signup').click(function(){
    var abort = false;
    $('not_valid').remove();
   $(':input[required]').each(function(){
       if($(this).val()===''){
            $(this).removeClass('valid').addClass('not_valid');
           abort = true;
       }
   });
   if(abort){
       return false;
   }else{
       return true;
   }
});
```

Comment: Try playing with `toggleClass`. Also you can replace your last statement with just `return abort`

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstand, you can just add an else to your if, and replace not-valid with valid if the field isn't empty.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple!

```
$('.submit_signup').click(function(){
  var abort = false;

  // do not forget the dot for classes
  $('.not_valid').removeClass('not_valid');

  // check inputs
  $(':input[required]').each(function(){
    if($(this).val()===''){
      $(this).removeClass('valid').addClass('not_valid');
      abort = true;
    }
  });

  // ! means not
  return !abort;
});
```